# Zurb Foundation is making my assets to load twice

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation, nested-forms

application.css:

```
*= require_self
*= require foundation_and_overrides
*= require_tree .
*/
```

Application.js:

```
*= require jquery
*= require jquery_ujs
*= require foundation
*= require jquery_nested_form
*= require highcharts/highcharts
*= require turbolinks
*= require_tree .
$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

Application.html.erb (generated by foundation):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<!-- Uncomment to make IE8 render like IE7 -->
<!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" /> -->

<!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Untitled" %></title>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/custom.modernizr" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>

  <body>

  <header>
    <nav class="top-bar">
    <%= render 'layouts/nav' %>
    </nav>
    <%= render 'layouts/flash' %>
  </header>

  <section>
    <%= yield %>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </footer>


    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  </body>
</html>
```

development logs:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/nav/_director.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/nav/_director.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/nav/_manager.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/nav/_manager.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/nav/_supervisor.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/nav/_supervisor.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flash.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flash.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 14ms (Views: 12.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 14ms (Views: 12.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.alerts.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.alerts.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.forms.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.forms.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.joyride.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.joyride.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.clearing.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.clearing.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.magellan.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.magellan.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.orbit.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.orbit.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.reveal.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.reveal.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.section.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.section.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.cookie.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.cookie.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.topbar.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.topbar.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.interchange.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.interchange.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.tooltips.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.tooltips.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.placeholder.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.placeholder.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.abide.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.abide.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/jquery_nested_form.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/jquery_nested_form.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/index.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/foundation/index.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/highcharts/highcharts.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/highcharts/highcharts.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 13:27:35 +0100
```

As you can see, it is loading each assets twice. Furthermore, I am using `nested_form`, so when I click to add a nested form it adds many forms and not only one.
However, if I refresh the page, the form works as expected.

I have tried to mode the `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` to the top, but the nav menu does not work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your nav work properly, try adding `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'` to your `Gemfile` and then add `//= require jquery.turbolinks` to your application.js - that should take care of all the $(document).ready binds in the app.

Then move your javascript tag back to the head.

And, btw, it seems like the server is getting 2 simultaneous requests (e.g. from 2 livereloaded tabs in the browser), that could also be the case.

Comment: `jquery-turbolinks` solved the loading problem. I'm still getting 2 simultaneous requests, but only in development envirounment. In production is everything working well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with double server logs, turns out it was an issue with the Rails STDOUT logger.

Check out the following links:

[A log that looks exactly like yours](https://github.com/gkop/heroku-rails-4-duplicate-logs/issues/1)

[Issue tracked here](https://github.com/heroku/rails_stdout_logging/issues/1)

Check your page request timeline with Chrome. If your page's assets are only loading once and getting logged twice this is most likely the same problem.